# what is wrong in my python code?

Tags: python

```
#!usr/bin/python

listofnames = []

names = input("Pls enter how many of names:")
x = 1

for x in range(0, names):
    inname = input("Enter the name " + str(x))
    listofnames.append(inname)


print listofnames
```

---

error

```
inname = input("Enter the name " + str(x))
```

File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'Jhon' is not defined

Comment: Note that you could do this with a list comprehension; the code pattern `var = []; for ...: var.append( ... )` is the clue. `listofnames = [ raw_input( "Name %d? " % x ) for x in range( int( raw_input( "How many names? " ) ) ) ]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` gets text from the user which is then interpreted as Python code (hence it's trying to evaluate the thing you entered, `Jhon`). You need `raw_input` for both of them and you'll need to convert the number entered (since it's a string) to an integer for your `range`.

```
#!usr/bin/python

listofnames = []
names = 0
try:
    names = int(raw_input("Pls enter how many of names:"))
except:
    print "Problem with input"

for x in range(0, names):
    inname = raw_input("Enter the name %d: "%(x))
    listofnames.append(inname)

print listofnames
```

Comment: +1: We're on the same page :).  In your script you probably want to blow up in the int conversion throws an exception and check for `ValueError` instead of a catch all exception.

Comment: Good idea, I'll print an error message. But I usually just catch all exceptions in quick'n'dirty scripts since they may enter CTRL-D and give me an EOFError.

Comment: Thank you "Paxdiablo" :) Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

Use `raw_input` instead. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input.  `input` will do the same thing as `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, so entering in `Jhon` will try to find the symbol `Jhon` within the file (which doesn't exist). So for your existing script you'd have to input `'Jhon'` (notice the set of quotes) in the prompt so the eval will convert the value to a string.

Here's the excerpt warning from the [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) documentation.

> **Warning**
>
> This function is not safe from user
>   errors! It expects a valid Python
>   expression as input; if the input is
>   not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError
>   will be raised. Other exceptions may
>   be raised if there is an error during
>   evaluation. (On the other hand,
>   sometimes this is exactly what you
>   need when writing a quick script for
>   expert use.)

Below is the corrected version:

```
#!usr/bin/python

# The list is implied with the variable name, see my comment below.
names = []

try:
    # We need to convert the names input to an int using raw input.
    # If a valid number is not entered a `ValueError` is raised, and
    # we throw an exception.  You may also want to consider renaming
    # names to num_names.  To be "names" sounds implies a list of
    # names, not a number of names.  
    num_names = int(raw_input("Pls enter how many of names:"))
except ValueError:
    raise Exception('Please enter a valid number.')

# You don't need x=1. If you want to start your name at 1 
# change the range to start at 1, and add 1 to the number of names.
for x in range(1, num_names+1)):
    inname = raw_input("Enter the name " + str(x))
    names.append(inname)

print names
```

NOTE: This is for Python2.x.  Python3.x has fixed the input vs. raw_input confusion as explained in the other answers.

Comment: @Freeman: You're welcome.  I added a bit more comments to the code about variable naming, and handling the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In python3, `input()` now works like `raw_input()`. However to get your code to work with Python3 a couple of changes are still required

```
#!usr/bin/python3

listofnames = []

names = int(input("Pls enter how many of names:"))
x = 1

for x in range(0, names):
    inname = input("Enter the name " + str(x))
    listofnames.append(inname)


print(listofnames)
```