# input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, nameerror

I am getting an error when I try to run this simple script:

```
input_variable = input("Enter your name: ")
print("your name is" + input_variable)
```

Let's say I type in "dude", the error I am getting is:

```
  line 1, in <module>
    input_variable = input("Enter your name: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dude' is not defined
```

I am running Mac OS X 10.9.1 and I am using the Python Launcher app that came with the install of Python 3.3 to run the script.

Comment: Are you sure it's Python 3.3? I would expect `input` to behave this way, but only in 2.7. What does it say when you run `python --version` from a command prompt? Alternatively, what if you write `import sys; print(sys.version)` at the beginning of your script?

Comment: You're not running Python 3. You're running Python 2, somehow (I'm not familiar with this "Python Launcher" app)

Comment: Put as first line `import sys` and as second line `print(sys.version_info)` in order to ascertain which version you are using.

Comment: I did what Kevin said and it is version 2.7.5! I'm not sure how though. I downloaded and installed version 3.3, in my applications folder there is a folder that is called "Python 3.3" inside that folder there is an app called "Python Launcher" and I am running my scripts by dragging and dropping them onto the Python Launcher app. How come I am still using 2.7 when I am using the 3.3 launcher app?

Comment: @chillpenguin Please include in the question that you are using 2.7. Thats crucial to answer this question.

Comment: @thefourtheye: The whole question is basically "why is Python Launcher running python 2 instead of, sensibly, Python 3", so... not really.

Comment: I just edited my question to include that. I did not know that I was using 2.7.5 until I followed Kevin's instructions.

Comment: @chillpenguin: check out the Preferences dialog for Python Launcher. Apparently it doesn't default to running the version it was installed with, which is... dumb. (I've never used it myself; I find using the Terminal is better...)

Comment: Thank you Wooble. Right now under prefences it says "interpreter: /usr/bin/pythonw " Is that what I want to change? What do I change it to?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as first line

Answer (score 299):

**TL;DR**

`input` function in Python 2.7, evaluates whatever your enter, as a Python expression. If you simply want to read strings, then use `raw_input` function in Python 2.7, which will not evaluate the read strings.

If you are using Python 3.x, `raw_input` has been renamed to `input`. Quoting the [Python 3.0 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins),

> `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`. That is, the new `input()` function reads a line from `sys.stdin` and returns it with the trailing newline stripped. It raises `EOFError` if the input is terminated prematurely. To get the old behavior of `input()`, use `eval(input())`

---

**In Python 2.7**, there are two functions which can be used to accept user inputs. One is [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) and the other one is [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). You can think of the relation between them as follows

```
input = eval(raw_input)
```

Consider the following piece of code to understand this better

```
>>> dude = "thefourtheye"
>>> input_variable = input("Enter your name: ")
Enter your name: dude
>>> input_variable
'thefourtheye'
```

`input` accepts a string from the user and evaluates the string in the current Python context. When I type `dude` as input, it finds that `dude` is bound to the value `thefourtheye` and so the result of evaluation becomes `thefourtheye` and that gets assigned to `input_variable`.

If I enter something else which is not there in the current python context, it will fail will the `NameError`.

```
>>> input("Enter your name: ")
Enter your name: dummy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dummy' is not defined
```

**Security considerations with Python 2.7's `input`:**

Since whatever user types is evaluated, it imposes security issues as well. For example, if you have already loaded `os` module in your program with `import os`, and then the user types in

```
os.remove("/etc/hosts")
```

this will be evaluated as a function call expression by python and it will be executed. If you are executing Python with elevated privileges, `/etc/hosts` file will be deleted. See, how dangerous it could be?

To demonstrate this, let's try to execute `input` function again.

```
>>> dude = "thefourtheye"
>>> input("Enter your name: ")
Enter your name: input("Enter your name again: ")
Enter your name again: dude
```

Now, when `input("Enter your name: ")` is executed, it waits for the user input and the user input is a valid Python function invocation and so that is also invoked. That is why we are seeing `Enter your name again:` prompt again.

So, you are better off with `raw_input` function, like this

```
input_variable = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
```

If you need to convert the result to some other type, then you can use appropriate functions to convert the string returned by `raw_input`. For example, to read inputs as integers, use the `int` function, like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20449433/1903116).

**In python 3.x**, there is only one function to get user inputs and that is called [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), which is equivalent to Python 2.7's `raw_input`.

Answer (score 61):

You are running Python 2, not Python 3.  For this to work in Python 2, use `raw_input`.

```
input_variable = raw_input ("Enter your name: ")
print ("your name is" + input_variable)
```

Answer (score 18):

Since you are writing for Python 3.x, you'll want to begin your script with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

If you use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

It will default to Python 2.x. These go on the first line of your script, if there is nothing that starts with *#!* (aka the shebang).

If your scripts just start with:

```
#! python
```

Then you can change it to:

```
#! python3
```

Although this shorter formatting is only recognized by a few programs, such as the launcher, so it is not the best choice.

The first two examples are much more widely used and will help ensure your code will work on any machine that has Python installed.

Answer (score 9):

I also encountered this issue with a module that was supposed to be compatible for python 2.7 and 3.7

what i found to fix the issue was importing:

```
from six.moves import input
```

this fixed the usability for both interpreters

you can read more about the six library [here](https://pythonhosted.org/six/)

Answer (score 6):

You should use `raw_input` because you are using python-2.7. When you use `input()` on a variable (for example: `s = input('Name: ')`), it will execute the command ON the Python environment without saving what you wrote on the variable (`s`) and create an error if what you wrote is not defined.

`raw_input()` will save correctly what you wrote on the variable (for example: `f = raw_input('Name : ')`), and it will not execute it in the Python environment without creating any possible error:

```
input_variable = raw_input('Enter Your Name : ')
print("Your Name Is  : " + (input_variable))
```

Answer (score 5):

**For python 3 and above**

```
s = raw_input()
```

it will solve the problem on pycharm IDE
if you are solving on online site exactly hackerrank then use:

```
s = input()
```

Comment: `raw_input` is not defined in Python 3. Is that a typo of "Python 2"?

Answer (score 5):

```
input_variable = input ("Enter your name: ")
print ("your name is" + input_variable)
```

You have to enter input in either single or double quotes

```
Ex:'dude' -> correct

    dude -> not correct
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `raw_input` rather than `input` if you simply want to read strings.

```
print("Enter your name: ")
x = raw_input()
print("Hello, "+x)
```

[image: Image contains the output screen]

Answer (score 4):

We are using the following that works both **python 2 and python 3**

```
#Works in Python 2 and 3:
try: input = raw_input
except NameError: pass
print(input("Enter your name: "))
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to fix these issues,

- 1st is simple without code change that is
  **run your script by Python3,** 
  **if you still want to run on python2** then
  after running your python script, when you are entering the input keep in mind

  1. if you want to enter `string` then just start typing down with "input goes with double-quote" and it will work in python2.7 and
  2. if you want to enter character then use the input with a single quote like 'your input goes here'
  3. if you want to enter number not an issue you simply type the number
- 2nd way is with code  changes
  use the below import and run with any version of python

  1. `from six.moves import input`
  2. Use `raw_input()` function instead of `input()` function in your code with any import
  3. sanitise your code with `str()` function like `str(input())` and then assign to any variable

**As error implies**:
 name 'dude' is not defined 
i.e. for python 'dude' become variable here and it's not having any value of python defined type assigned
so only its crying like baby so if we define a 'dude' variable and assign any value and pass to it, it will work but that's not what we want as we don't know what user will enter and moreover we want to capture the user input.

> **Fact about these method:**
>   `input()` function: This function takes the value and type of the input you enter as it is without modifying it type.
>  `raw_input()`
>   function: This function explicitly converts the input you give into type string,
>
> **Note:**
>  The vulnerability in input() method lies in the fact that
>   the variable accessing the value of input can be accessed by anyone
>   just by using the name of variable or method.

Answer (score 3):

You could either do:

```
x = raw_input("enter your name")
print "your name is %s " % x
```

or:

```
x = str(input("enter your name"))
print "your name is %s" % x
```

Comment: raw_input fixed the issue for me

Comment: But raw_input() isn't available in Python 3.

Comment: @carthurs yeah input is string by default now

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that may run into this issue, turns out that even if you include `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of your script, the shebang is ignored if the file isn't executable.

To determine whether or not your file is executable:

- run `./filename.py` from the command line
- if you get `-bash: ./filename.py: Permission denied`, run `chmod a+x filename.py`
- run `./filename.py` again

If you've included `import sys; print(sys.version)` as Kevin suggested, you'll now see that the script is being interpreted by python3

Answer (score 2):

Good contributions the previous ones.

```
import sys; print(sys.version)

def ingreso(nombre):
    print('Hi ', nombre, type(nombre))

def bienvenida(nombre):
    print("Hi "+nombre+", bye ")

nombre = raw_input("Enter your name: ")

ingreso(nombre)
bienvenida(nombre)

#Works in Python 2 and 3:
try: input = raw_input
except NameError: pass
print(input("Your name: "))
```

```
Enter your name: Joe
('Hi ', 'Joe', <type 'str'>)
Hi Joe, bye 

Your name: Joe
Joe
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change which python you're using with your IDE, if you've already downloaded python 3.x it shouldn't be too hard to switch. But your script works fine on python 3.x, I would just change

```
print ("your name is" + input_variable)
```

to

```
print ("your name is", input_variable)
```

Because with the comma it prints with a whitespace in between `your name is` and whatever the user inputted. AND: if you're using 2.7 just use `raw_input` instead of input.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an input function which is compatible with both Python 2.7 and Python 3+:
(Slightly modified answer by @Hardian) to avoid `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment` error

```
def input_compatible(prompt=None):
    try:
        input_func = raw_input
    except NameError:
        input_func = input
    return input_func(prompt)
```

Also here is another alternative without a `try` block:

```
def input_compatible(prompt=None):
    input_func = raw_input if "raw_input" in __builtins__.__dict__ else input
    return input_func(prompt)
```

Comment: If you need to support Python 2 and Python 3, you should be using the `six` library, which provides `six.input`. There's no reason to catch a `NameError` every single time you call `input_compatible` if you are using Python 3.

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to depend on any non standard packages, for example when writing a portable shell script, so this answer has it place and justification.

Comment: That still doesn't excuse using a `try` statement every single time you try to call the function. `raw_input` isn't going to suddenly appear while your script is executing; it's either available at the beginning or not at all. Also, if you need compatibility between both versions, there is likely a *lot* of stuff you are going to need to accommodate, and it doesn't make sense not to use `six`.

Comment: Pardon @chepner, but I don't agree with you. First, you didn't provide a better alternative for use cases that require a portable solution and cannot use *any* non-standard package. Since you haven't, I edited my answer to include such.  Second, while I normally agree with you that you shouldn't use `try` block for situation you can easily check in advance, in this case, it doesn't have any performance downside and looks cleaner than the alternative in my opinion.

Comment: Not every problem can or should be solved with the standard library alone.

Comment: `__builtins__.__dict__.get("input") is None` is never true. You could check `if 'raw_input' in __builtins__.__dict__`. Or you could just check `sys.version_info` to see which version of Python you're on.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, modified it.