# How to check if input/raw_input contains an item in a list. Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
name = input(str('Please enter your name'))
names= ('name1','name2','nameetc')
if name in names:
    print "hi",name
```

If I use this code and user inputs `name1`, I get an error `name1 is not defined`. If the user puts `"name1"` in quotes then it works. I could ask the user to put the name in quotes, but then how do I check to ensure that it was before continuing. Preferably I would only have to ask for the name though. If I replace each `str` in the list with an int the code works fine. How do I make it work with a `str` in a list?

Comment: You don't have to wrap `'Please enter your name'` with `str()` - it is a string already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/python-input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python2 `input` evaluates the string the user types. So when you input `name1`, python tries to find the value of the variable `name1`. The variable doesn't exist and you get the not defined exception. Use `raw_input` instead that just returns the string:

```
name = raw_input('Please enter your name')
if name in ('name1', 'name2', 'nameetc'):
    print "hi",name
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `raw_input()`. In Python 2, `input()` tries to evaluate the entered string.