# NameError in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

For learning (and testing) I made this simple dictionary with a small query in Python. but I allways get a `NameError` and I just can't figure out what's wrong

**the Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def getColor(color):
    Colors = {"red":"FF0000","green":"00FF00","blue":"0000FF"}
    return Colors[color]

inputColor = str(input("Please input a color: "))
getColor(inputColor)
```

**The Traceback:**

```
Please input a color: blue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DictionaryTest", line 7, in <module>
    inputColor = str(input("Please input a color: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'blue' is not defined
```

**the Solution**

apperently there was a solution for this problem here is my working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def getColor(color):
    Colors = {"red":"FF0000","green":"00FF00","blue":"0000FF"}
    print Colors[str(color)]

inputColor = str(raw_input("Please input a color: "))
getColor(inputColor)
```

Comment: You created a dictionary in the variable called `Farben`, but where is `Colors` defined?

Comment: crap this isn't an error, I translated my code to english for better understanding and forgot to translate this one. sorry, changed it.

Comment: Detailed explanation can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21122817/1903116)

Comment: I didn't notice at first, but it says `python3` in the first line with the environment.

Comment: If the OP is using Python 3, is this really a duplicate?

Comment: seems so, changed `input` to `raw_input` and it worked. (see my solution in the question)

Comment: @globus243 then i should tell you - you python3 is a fake! :D how do you run the script: like ./script_file.py or python script_file.py ?

Comment: @Reishin care to elaborate? always keen to learn!

Comment: @globus243 sorry, what? Your code sample use hash-bang with python3 binary to execute, but you able to fix the issue using solution for python2. It's make question unclear

Comment: oh, didn't see the second part of your answer. this code will run inside Yowsup ( https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup ) which is a Python CommandLine WhatsApp Client, but I'm testing it like `python3 ./script.py`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using Python 2 and therefore need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` (no need to cast to `str()`).