# Python error while getting value

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am using Python version 2.7.3. When I try to run the below code, an error is throwing,

```
>>> value = input("get value: ")

    get value: hello

    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

    NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

Comment: Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/python-input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in previous answers use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. Reason for this is that `input()` method interprets the value provided by user.
If the user e.g. puts in an integer value, the input function returns this integer value. If the user on the other hand inputs a list, the function will return a list. 
Since you want to input a string. If you don't wrap your name into quotes, Python takes your name as a `variable`. So, the error message makes sense.

Comment: oh!!! thanks shakthimaan... now I got the difference between variable name and string value while passing as input....

Comment: @Green Also this is only true for `Python 2.x`. In `Python 3.x` `input()` returns strings.

Answer (score 5):

When passing a string use `"` or put `hello` inside `"`.`"hello"` something like this.

or

simply use `raw_input()`

Answer (score 2):

If you want input a number use `input()` 
If you want to input a string(like name) use `raw_input()`:

```
>>> val = input('get value:')
get value:100
>>> val
100
>>> string = raw_input("get value:")
get value:hello
>>> string
'hello'
```