# Name not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I am writing a simple input and I keep getting an error. Fir example if I type in 'Eagle' it get name error eagle is not defined. Why is this?

```
print("The new word?")
newword = input()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/python-input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: Probably just as well it's a duplicate, as the answers so far are... not great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raw_input` instead if you don't want to evaluate the expression supplied. By default python evaluates whatever you supply to `input` as python expression, raising the name error.

```
newword = raw_input('the new word')
```

Otherwise, if you are meant on using `input`, then you need to enclose your entry string in quotes. Then python would consider it a string eliminating the NameError. Supply `'Eagle'` instead of `Eagle`. Moreover, its better to supply the prompt string in input parameters i.e.

```
newword = input('The new word')

#supply 'Eagle' (in quotes)
```

Comment: I would use imput parameters but I've been told to follow strict pseudo code so its like this. I've never had to do enclose in quotes before, why is this?

Comment: Yeah ... that's what I said

Comment: @Bill sorry I thought you were replying on answer

Comment: is there anyway of not getting python to evaluate?

Comment: use raw_input instead