# Python: input accepts integer but crashes on a string

Tags: python

For a practice problem in my homework, i'm making a guessing game that starts off by asking for a number. I'm trying to implement a way that prints "invalid input" when given a string, but i get an error message. here is my code:

```
def get_input():
    '''
    Continually prompt the user for a number, 1,2 or 3 until
    the user provides a good input. You will need a type conversion.
    :return: The users chosen number as an integer
    '''
    guess=int(input("give me 1,2,3"))
    while True:
        if guess==1 or guess==2 or guess==3:
            return guess
        else:
            print "Invalid input!"

        guess=int(input("give me 1,2,3"))
```

I get this message when I put in a string such as

```
hello/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 /Users/bob/PycharmProjects/untitled/warmup/__init__.py
```

give me `1,2,3hello`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/untitled/warmup/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    get_input()
  File "/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/untitled/warmup/__init__.py", line 43, in get_input
    guess=int(input("give me 1,2,3"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You may use `try` `catch` for this scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/python-input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: **input('enter an integer')** and **raw_input('enter a string')**

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `raw_input` for python2, input tries to evaluate the string so it looks for a variable called `name` and errors as there is no variable called `name` defined anywhere. You should never use `input` in python2, it is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())` which has obvious security risks.

So to spell it out more clearly, **don't** use input to take input from a user in python2, use `raw_input()` and in your case take the `raw_input` using a `try/except` catching a `ValueError`.

```
def get_input():
    '''
    Continually prompt the user for a number, 1,2 or 3 until
    the user provides a good input. You will need a type conversion.
    :return: The users chosen number as an integer
    '''

    while True:
        try:
            guess = int(raw_input("give me 1,2,3"))
            if guess in (1, 2, 3):
                return guess
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print("Invalid input!")
```

The fact you are just cheking for 1,2 or 3 means you could also just do the casting after you confirm:

```
def get_input():
    '''
    Continually prompt the user for a number, 1,2 or 3 until
    the user provides a good input. You will need a type conversion.
    :return: The users chosen number as an integer
    '''

    while True:
        guess = raw_input("give me 1,2,3")
        if guess in ("1", "2", "3"):
            return int(guess)
        print("Invalid input!")
```

Comment: this will solve the problem but it looks more like a comment then an answer

Comment: @VigneshKalai, this is the answer to the question, *input accepts integer but crashes on a string*,what do you think is causing that?

Comment: I am not saying you're answer is wrong it is just that you could add a link stating about this behaviour of the input method

Comment: Answered the question! Now you've added code, just one comment doesn't `print "Invalid Input"` for int inputs  < 1 or > 4, you could just pass on the exception and print if it loops (given the return exits the loop).

Comment: @achampion, True, easier just to pass and print.

Answer (score 1):

You should to verify the input type before converting into a int:

```
guess = raw_input("give me 1,2,3")

while True:
   if guess == '1' or guess == '2' or guess == '3':
      return int(guess)
   else:
      print "Invalid input!"

   guess = raw_input("give me 1,2,3")
```

Comment: `raw_input` always returns a string, `gess` doesn't exist and `else: pass` is completely useless.

Comment: @gre_gor you're right, i was a bit distracted. i assume my mistake here, sorry.

Comment: Now you are using `is` to test for equality, not a good idea! Also `else:pass` is redundant.

Comment: should i use `==` instead `is`?

Comment: yep. `is` would work at least using cpython but it is an implementation detail that should never be relied upon. `is` should be used for identity, `==` to test if two values are equal not necessarily the same object in memory

Comment: You still have a typo. And what is `get_input` doing here exactly?

Comment: @gre_gor is a suggestion to pass the input to function `arg`. Thx Padraic.

Comment: Your code is supposed to be inside that function and that function doesn't expect any arguments.

Comment: You still have a typo and he wants the input returned not just printed.

Comment: @gre_gor i've noticed but dont makes sence, if you use a `return` in a function it will be used after, and you expect a int in this case, if not he return nothing. that dont makes sence to me but i edited it

Comment: This function never returns nothing since it's in an infinite loop and keeps asking for input. The only way to break from the loop, is to provide a valid input.

Comment: @ok thats a good observation, i didnt look in that way, but if the intended is the return it should be a return then :)