# Python receives `<function add>` from `input()` (newbie)

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, input

I am trying to make my first program in Python, however, I am having a problem.

Why is `op1` not being assigned the value I input?

```
print ("Hello user")
num1 = int(input("Choose a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Choose another number: "))
op1 = (input("Choose an operation [add, multiply, minus, divide]: "))
print (op1)
```

No matter what I enter into `op1` I always receive this message from `print (op1)`:

```
<function add at 0x10cff1938>
```

Comment: Is the error "NameError: name 'add' is not defined"? That would mean that you are using python2 not python3.

Comment: In python 2, `input` evaluates a string as a python statement. `raw_input` is used to input strings.

Comment: error is "<function add at 0x10cff1938>"    no matter what i input for 'op1' i always receive that error for 'print (op1)'

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 2.7._, then if you're reading in strings, you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/python-input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined).

Comment: I am using python 3.5

Comment: <function add at 0x10cff1938>

Comment: This code works for me, with python 3.4.  Are you **sure** you're using python 3?

Comment: Hi John, i have just read another question with a similar problem. Turns out i am not running python 3. I downloaded and installed python 3.5 however, i am still running 2.7. Do you know how I can change this please? I am using mac.

Comment: @dandannn: you can run `python3` or `python3.5` instead of just `python` to execute a specific version. You'll want to leave Python 2 as the system default.