# getting the value of a key in python

Tags: python

I used dictionaries here:

```
percentage = {'a':75.5, 'b':73, 'c':78, 'd':68, 'e':68}
name = input("enter a name: ")
if percentage.has_key(name):
 print dict[name]
else:
 print "no data"
```

---

when i've given a name(for example 'a') ,it is showing "unhandled Nameerror -name 'a' is not defined" .whats the solution for it.
thank you.

Comment: Are you really using `dict[name]` instead of `percentage[name]`?

Comment: What Python version are you using? Look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21122817/4897175 .

Comment: Assuming you are requesting a key from the correct dictionary, you want to use `get`.  `df.get(key)` will return the value from the dictionary if it is present, otherwise it will return None.  You can also specify the value to return if the key is not found, e.g. `df.get(key, 'NA')`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Python 2.7 or Python 3?

If you're using 2.7, then you need to use `raw_input()`, since `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, which you probably don't want:

```
name = raw_input("enter a name: ")
```

If you're using 3, then `print` needs to be a function:

```
print(dict[name])
...
print("no data")
```

However, common to both versions, some fixing needs to be applied.

First thing is, you don't need to use `has_key()`. I'm pretty sure this is defunct now, so the most pythonic way to go around this is do:

```
if name in percentage:
```

Easy right? Next, you need to print the value, and to do that, the syntax is: `dictionary[key] = value`. You seem to have it, but you've forgotten to reference your own dictionary and instead used the built-in type `dict`. It should be:

```
print percentage[name]
```

So all together (Python 2.7):

```
percentage = {'a':75.5, 'b':73, 'c':78, 'd':68, 'e':68}
name = raw_input("enter a name: ")
if percentage.has_key(name):
   print percentage[name]
else:
   print "no data"
```

Comment: If the OP was using Python 3 there would be a `SyntaxError` before it could produce a `NameError`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Ah, didn't know about that. I don't use Python 3 myself

Comment: Yep. In older versions of Python 3 it gives a generic traceback, but it was eventually changed to say `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to reference the name of your dictionary:

```
percentage = {'a':75.5, 'b':73, 'c':78, 'd':68, 'e':68}
name = input("enter a name: ")
if percentage.has_key(name):
   print percentage[name]
else:
   print "no data"
```

Comment: That fixes an obvious problem in the code, but not the one that OP actually experienced and asked about.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to refer to your dictionary by its actual name, `percentage`, not `dict`. `dict` is the type and function, not the object you created.

Secondly, there's an easier way to do this, with the `get` method:

```
percentage = {'a':75.5, 'b':73, 'c':78, 'd':68, 'e':68}
name = input("enter a name: ")
print percentage.get(name, 'no data')
```

This will attempt to retrieve the value for `name`, and if there is no such key it will instead return the string `'no data'`.

Comment: You could even do `percentage.get(raw_input("enter a name: "), 'no data'))` if you wanted to :D

Comment: True; no need to save it if it isn't reused.

Comment: thank you.
and can we use lists or tupples for the same purpose.which is the better one.?

Comment: @lucky - Instead of a dictionary, you mean? If you want to do lookups like this, dictionaries are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use input in python2.7, because it return s a function instead of a string. Use raw_input instead please.