# Can anyone clarify why this simple code doesn't work in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had to code this for my midterm in my programming class, this is just a small part of the code.
keep in mind I'm really new to programming and this is an intro class to it.

we are learning 3.5 in class, and the code I wrote works fine in 3.5. however, I am starting to try and learn 2.7 and this code does not work on it:

```
print ("is student 1 here?")
attendence1 = input()
if attendence1 == "yes":
     student1 = "Y"
if attendence1 != (str("yes")):
student1 = ("N")
```

I'm just curious as to what the problem is between versions, and how 3.5 reads it vs how 2.7 does. I noticed that if I entered in my answer in 2.7 as a string, it would work, i.e:
Q:is student 2 here?
A: "yes"
does not cause an error, how ever
Q:is student 2 here?
A Yes
causes it to give me

```
attendence1 = input()
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

How would I make this code work on 2.7?

Comment: use `raw_input` instead of `input` for `2.7`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/python-input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

```
attendence1 = raw_input("is student 1 here?\n")
if attendence1 == "yes":
    student1 = "Y"
else:
    student1 = "N"
```

Need to use `raw_input()` instead of input. Also I think you wanted `"N"` not `("N")`

Comment: Thanks sir! wasn't sure