# using csv.DictReader, I want to search for a string and then print the row containing that string

Tags: python, csv

I have written a small script in Python to help me work with a large `.csv` file, but I'm currently having a few issues...

In the main of the program it prompts the user for an input, then calls a function referring to those options, like so... (only showing option one):

```
def Main():
    response = input('1, 2 or 3? ')

    if response == 1:
        ID = input('Enter your ID: ')
        Response_one(ID)
```

This function `Response_one` then opens the file, and I want it to search through and find where the `ID` variable that the user entered is present in the `.csv`, before printing that line. So far I have something like this:

```
def Response_one(ID):
    file_csv = csv.DictReader(open('my_file.csv'))
    for row in file_csv:
        if row['ID'] == ID:
            print row
```

I got to this point by following a few things online but I'm now stuck. I've been testing with IDs that I know exist within the table such as 'ENSG00000210049', but I get the error message:

```
NameError: name 'ENSG00000210049' is not defined
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some sample data for the CSV?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x? `input()` is different in these versions.

Comment: Hey, I'm using Python 2.x and my table looks a little like;

ID , Gene , Protein
1 ,  x1  ,  x2
2 ,  x3  ,  x4

My apologies for the awful table, it would seem that stackoverflow doesn't support tables..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main problem is that `input` function. You are getting the error because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122817/1561176):

> input function in Python 2.7, evaluates whatever your enter, as a
>   Python expression. If you simply want to read strings, then use
>   raw_input function in Python 2.7, which will not evaluate the read
>   strings.
>
> If you are using Python 3.x, raw_input has been renamed to input.
>   Quoting the Python 3.0 release notes

---

But lets give you a nice example to sort you out.

**data.csv**

```
ID,DATA
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

**Sample Code for Python 2**

```
id = raw_input('what id?: ')
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        if row['ID'] == id:
            print row
```

**Sample Code for Python 3**

```
id = input('what id?: ')
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        if row['ID'] == id:
            print row
```

**Example**

```
what id?: 1
{'ID': '1', 'DATA': 'a'}
```

Comment: Excellent, You can accept my answer if you feel it has answered your question. (I only remind you because you are a new user)

Comment: :P np, I was actually struggling to find the 'accept' button. Thanks so much