# How to add the array to this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import randint 
for i in range(5): 
    FN = (input("What is your name?"))
    firstletter = FN[:1] 
    SN = []
    first3letters = SN[:3]
    x = str(len(SN))
    sentence = str(randint(0,9))+(first3letters.lower())+(firstletter.upper()+(x))
    print(sentence)
```

I need to make an array, which will be printed and consist of the 5 usernames which get generated with this code. How would I do that?

Comment: `SN = []` and `first3letters = SN[:3]`, are you sure?

Comment: I think so? Is there an error in it? @sparkandshine

Comment: if so, `first2letters` always equals `[]`. Is it your desired situation?

Answer (score 1):

Convert `firstletter` and `first3letters` into a string before using `lower()` and `upper()`.

```
from random import randint 
for i in range(2): 
    FN = input("What is your name? ")
    firstletter = ''.join(FN[:1])

    SN = 'bMwGermany'
    first3letters = ''.join(SN[:3])
    x = str(len(SN))

    # sentence = str(randint(0,9))+(first3letters.lower())+(firstletter.upper()+(x))
    sentence = ''.join([str(randint(0, 9)), first3letters.lower(), firstletter.upper(), x])
    print(sentence)

# Test
$ python3 stackoverflow.py 
What is your name? hello
1bmwH8
What is your name? world
9bmwW8
```

Note that for Python2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. Refer to [Python input() error - NameError: name '…' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/python-input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined) for the detailed description.

Comment: @PennyHarvard, what did u mean 'doesn't work'? Logic error or ...?

Comment: @PennyHarvard, I added a test case.