# Python: NameError: name 'female' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python, I'm still in the newbie exercises...So have an exercise where I need to say the ideal weight to the height of the people,considering its genre...
So my code it is:

```
#!/ sr/bin/python
heigth = float(input("Enter the height of the person: "))
sex = input("Enter the person's gender:")

if(sex == "male"):
        pi = (72.7 * heigth) - 58
elif(sex=="female"):
        pi = (62.1 * heigth) - 44.7
else:
        print("Invalid gender")

print("The ideal weight for this person is:",pi)
```

And the error:

> File "n13.py", line 3, in 
>       sex = input("Enter the person's gender:")   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'female' is not defined

I don't understanding why the string in the comparison have to be defined if it is just a string??? o.O

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not receiving the same error on Python 3.x, maybe you we running it on Python 2.x? The error could happen on Python 2.x because `input()` is different between the two versions. If you are using Python 2.x, replace `input()` with `raw_input()`

Comment: Just replace input() with raw_input() in Python2

Comment: Also, `pi` in the last `print()` statement is undefined `if "Invalid gender"` is `True`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: If you copied and pasted your code then take a look at the `#!` line.  It should probably say `#!/usr/bin/python`, but the `u` is replaced by a space.

Answer (score 1):

You are running your code on Python 2, not Python 3. In Python 2 [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) evaluates the string it reads as Python code (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)).

If you will be using Python 2, replace `input` with [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

If you want to use Python 3, it is a good idea to change your shebang to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not working on python 3 so instant of input you have to use raw_input , so this works perfectly:

```
heigth = float(input("Enter the height of the person: "))
sex = raw_input("Enter the person's gender:")

if(sex == "male"):
        pi = (72.7 * heigth) - 58
elif(sex=="female"):
        pi = (62.1 * heigth) - 44.7
else:
        print("Invalid gender")

print("The ideal weight for this person is:",pi)
```

If you have python 3 on your machine i suggest you to use : #!/usr/bin/python3 and then the code is the same like yours