# Can not get keyword python scrapy crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
**keyword = ''

'''To obtain keyword'''
def test():`enter code here`
    keywords = list()
    while True:
        print('what do you want to do?(a: add a key word for searching, q:quit adding words and start)')
        command = input('command:')
        if command == 'a':
            word = input('keyword: ')
            if word not in keywords:
                keywords.append(word)
        elif command == 'q':
            break
        else:
            print('please input a valid command')
    if len(keywords) == 0:
        return
    search_string = ''
    for keyword in keywords:
        search_string += keyword
        search_string += '+'
    search_string = search_string[:-1]
    print(search_string)

    search_url = 'http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-' \
                 'bool.html&r=0&f=S&l=50&TERM1=' + search_string + '&FIELD1=&co1=AND&TERM2=&FIELD2=&d=PTXT'

    return search_url
'''Incoming url start the scrapy crawle'''
class Uspto(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'uspto'
    #allowed_domains = ['http://patft.uspto.gov/']
    #start_url = 'http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=0&f=S&l=50&TERM1=water&FIELD1=&co1=AND&TERM2=&FIELD2=&d=PTXT'

    allowed_domains = ["http://patft.uspto.gov"]
    keyword = test()

    start_urls = [
        #"http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=0&f=S&l=50&TERM1=python&FIELD1=&co1=AND&TERM2=&FIELD2=&d=PTXT",
        keyword,

    ]
**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PluLl.jpg) Error screenshot

**From the keyboard input keywords according to the keyword construction link, then start the crawler, the problem now is my access to the keyword method problems**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`, it seems that you are using python 2 instead of python 3, if so, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`:

```
command = raw_input("commands:")
```

`raw_input()` returns the string entered by the user, you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined) to know more details about `input` and `raw_input`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. It's really a version question. Thank you