# Error with user input() function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Very early stages of learning Python, my first language.  And this little bit of code is coppied straight out of the book.  Why do I get an error message?

```
name = input("Please tell me your name: ")
print("Hello, " + name + "!")
```

I enter my name, Eric, and get the following error:

```
File greeter.py, line 1, in ,<module>
    name = input("please tell me your name: ")
file '<string>, line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Eric is not defined
```

Comment: Check your Python version. If you are using Python 2.x you will need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Python 3.  but thanks!

Comment: ... make certain, because that is exactly the error message I would expect if you were actually running Python 2.

Comment: @ChiDrummer Please just substitute `input` with `raw_input` and see what happens.

Comment: Also, it looks like you retyped your error message manually instead of copy-pasting it out of the interpreter output. Please copy-paste instead of retyping code or error messages; retyping often introduces transcription errors that make it harder to debug things. You seem to have made a number of errors while retyping the error message in this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: now i'm having doubts

Comment: @ChiDrummer Can you please?

Comment: thought it was running python 3.  command prompt returns python 3.6.1 but text editor, somehow, is linked to a python folder Python27.  When I run the code with raw_input it works.  In trying to reconfigure my text editor, I cant find another Python file, ie Python36.  Can only find Python27

Comment: on windows python 3.6 defaults to a hidden folder when installing. for me, its in `C:\Users\<my name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32`.  Hope that helps you find it

Comment: Run `py -3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"` to see where the default Python 3 installation is located.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the raw_input() function instead. In early versions of python, the input would be run as regular python (through the eval() command). To get around this, use the raw_input() function.

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
print("Hello, " + name + "!")
>>>Please enter your name: Eric
>>>Hello, Eric!
```

Answer (score 1):

When executing your program through a terminal, try to type 'python3 fileName.py' instead of 'python fileName.py'
this may work if you are sure that you use python version 3, otherwise, just use raw_input assuming you are using an old version of python.