# What is this NameError and how do I fix it?

Tags: python

I am having difficulty understanding the concept in my book. I tried the coding example the book told me to try, but I get this NameError that I do not understand why it is an error.

This is my code:

```
name = input('What is your name?')
print(name)
```

This is my error message:

```
File "/Users/eric/Python Notes/Notes.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input('What is your name?\n')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'eric' is not defined
```

Edit: Thank you everyone who helped me understand this error. By default, Geany and VSCode were using Python2 as my interpreter. Changing it to Python3 fixed the problem. The raw_input() is correct also, because it is the correct syntax for Python2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178543/error-with-user-input-function-in-python-3

Comment: If you're following a course that is making you use Python 2, I would recommend finding another - Python 2 shouldn't be used anymore in 2022, unless it's as part of legacy software where it's inescapable.

Comment: It looks like you're on MacOS, so you should be running the python file with `python3 your_file_name.py` (assuming that your book is using Python 3, which it should be in this day and age)

Comment: "but it gives me the same error" Can you please confirm that you indeed run this code? I.e. that you see `name = raw_input('What is your name?')` in the error message

Comment: @Dmitry You were right. I forgot the compile so it was still running with input() instead of raw_input()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some solution for your problem:

1. if you are using python 2.x you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`
2. check your python version by typing `python --version` or excute your python file in terminal with `python3 yourfilename.py`
   instead of `python yourfilename.py`

Comment: I am using MacOS and VSCode as my IDE. How do I make it so that I am running on Python3 instead of Python2?

Comment: open a terminal in vscode from Terminal -->new Terminal
in opened terminal type `python3 notes.py`