# python invalid syntax error when asking for users input in terminal

Tags: python, syntax, terminal

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd Documents/attendance/
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/attendance $ ./Attendance.py 
Please swipe your card: %CHEND151?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Attendance.py", line 15, in <module>
    eqid = input('Please swipe your card: ').strip().upper()
  File "<string>", line 1
    %CHEND151?
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/attendance $
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error? is it because of the `%` because I try without it and it still happens.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/attendance $ ./Attendance.py 
Please swipe your card: chend151
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Attendance.py", line 15, in <module>
    eqid = input('Please swipe your card: ').strip().upper()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'chend151' is not defined
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/attendance $
```

Comment: You're probably using Python 2 in which case you need to use `raw_input()` rather than `input()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: @ChristianDean ahh yes that works, thank you :D, how would I make it run using python 3? would I have to change the `#!/usr/bin/python` part?

Comment: @Sirsyorrz Honestly I'm not 100% sure because I'm not very familiar with Linux shebangs. I guess you would need to change it to `#!/usr/bin/python3` to use Python 3?

Comment: A python3 shebang should work as long as Python 3 is installed