# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing in Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

Write the code to convert Temperature:

```
#TempConvert.py
val = input("Input Temperature(eg. 32C): ")
if val[-1] in ['C','c']:
    f = 1.8 * float(val[0:-1]) + 32
    print("Converted Temperture : %.2fF"%f)
elif val[-1] in ['F','f']:
    c = (float(val[0:-1]) - 32) / 1.8
    print("Converted Temperture: %.2fC"%c)
else:
    print("Input Error")
```

When runing the code in Python2.7, get an error :

```
    enter code ============= RESTART: D:\workshop_for_Python\TempConvert -2.py =============
Input Temperture(eg. 32C): 33C

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workshop_for_Python\TempConvert -2.py", line 2, in <module>
    val = input("Input Temperture(eg. 32C): ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    33C
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsinghere
```

Any idea whats the issue?Thanks a lot~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2):

The source of error is use of `input()` for taking input as it only allows reading of integer value. So only modification in code will be use of `raw_input()` :

```
#TempConvert.py
val = raw_input("Input Temperature(eg. 32C): ")
if val[-1] in ['C','c']:
    f = 1.8 * float(val[0:-1]) + 32
    print("Converted Temperture : %.2fF"%f)
elif val[-1] in ['F','f']:
    c = (float(val[0:-1]) - 32) / 1.8
    print("Converted Temperture: %.2fC"%c)
else:
    print("Input Error")
```