# Input undefined | python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am making a simple program that repeats what I input. The current code is this:

```
print("Please enter your username.")
n = str(input(">> "))
print("Welcome, ",n)
```

However, when I run it and input, say, John, it would print the error: John is undefined, or something very similar to that. Any ideas why? Solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `raw_input()` instead. 
Using `input()` requires the use of "" when you enter the name and want it to be interpreted as a string.

```
>>> n = input(">> ")
>> "john"
>>> print n
john
```

When using `raw_input()` you can do the following:

```
>>> n = raw_input(">> ")
>> john
>>> print n
john
```

`input()` interprets an unquoted string input as a variable, i.e you can do something like

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = input()
>> x
>>> print y
5
```

See also https://www.python-course.eu/input.php for further information.