# Python 3 input() from command line

Tags: python-3.x, input, command-line

I use the **s=input("")** command in a Python 3 script. When I run it from command line (Ubuntu 14.04) and type for example hello  I get this error **NameError: name 'hello' is not defined**. However when I type "Hello" everything is fine. I have seen in other examples that it is not necessary to have the "" in my input. What do I have to change?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined

Comment: You're probably running Python 2. What specific command are you using to run your script?

Comment: Like others have mentioned, you're probably using Python 2. When you open the terminal to run the script, did you use the command "python" or "python3"

Comment: yeah that was the problem 
I did not ran it in my virtual environment where I had the python3.
Thank you for your replies