# How do I fix this EOF error

Tags: python-3.x

My code is as follows and enclosed is a link to the screenshot of the error. It wants me to test for number of characters in a sentence

```
def get_num_of_characters(inputStr):
    return len(inputStr) 

def output_without_whitespace(inputStr):
    output=''
    for i in range(0,len(inputStr)):
        if(inputStr[i]==' ') or (inputStr[i]=='\t'):
    exit 
    else: 
        output+=inputStr[i]
return output

# if __name__=="__main__":

inputStr=input("Enter a sentence or phrase: \n")
print("You entered:",inputStr)
print("\nNumber of characters:",get_num_of_characters(inputStr))
print("String with no whitespace:",output_without_whitespace(inputStr))
```

Enter a sentence or phrase: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zyLabsUnitTestRunner.py", line 4, in 
    from zyLabsUnitTest import test_passed
  File "/home/runner/local/submission/unit_test_student_code/zyLabsUnitTest.py", line 1, in 
    from main import get_num_of_characters
  File "/home/runner/local/submission/unit_test_student_code/main.py", line 15, in 
    inputStr=input("Enter a sentence or phrase: \n")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Include the traceback in the code as text, and not as an image.

Comment: Did changing it to `raw_input` not work?

Comment: hey Kevin, it did not work

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using `python-3.x`. In `2.x`, I changed:

```
inputStr=input("Enter a sentence or phrase: \n")
```

To:

```
inputStr=raw_input("Enter a sentence or phrase: \n")
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122817/8811872) for a more in-depth explanation between the two.