# python 3 NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

**Edit**: Thank you for your helpful answers! I downloaded Python 3.7.0 but you are right, my Mac is running Python 2.7.  I have homework now :) Figure out how to get it running 3.7.  I will come back if I have more questions.  Thank you!

Beginner here.  I'm getting NameError when executing in Mac with Python Launcher. When testing in Python 3.7.0 Shell it works ok.  I've read other answers to NameError questions, but do not understand what I'm doing wrong. Help is appreciated.

**Code used**

```
first_name = input ("Hi, what's your first name? ")
print ("Hi," , first_name)
```

**Error received**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imperio/Documents/pythonpractice/Name.py", line 1, in <module>
   first_name = input ("Hi, what's your first name? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Imperio' is not defined
```

Comment: That's not Python 3.7. You're on Python 2.

Comment: Thank you.  I downloaded Python 3.7. from python.org. I'm using a beginners Python book that's based on Python 3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because you are not executing it using Python 3+.

Please check the output of `python -V` to see which version you are executing your code with.

On mac you may already have both installed, Python 3 is sometimes aliased under `python3 file.py`

Here's your program converted to valid Python2:

```
first_name = raw_input ("Hi, what's your first name? ")
print ("Hi, {}".format(first_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running Python 2.  In Python 2, `input` executes the input.  `raw_input` just returns the string entered.

Here's an example:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> z = 3
>>> print input('variable? ')
variable? x                       # Note output is the value of the variable
1
>>> print input('variable? ')
variable? w                          # Variable 'w' doesn't exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'w' is not defined
>>> print raw_input('variable? ')       # Raw input just returns the input.
variable? x
x
```