# python variable is not defined using print function

Tags: python

After running the below code, python prompt error and tell me name "tony" is not defined.

```
print('Hello Sam, this is Javis')
#let user enter their name, "nm" being the variable
nm = input('Please tell me your name => ')
print('It is definitely nice to meet you',nm,'!')
```

I input name as "Tony"

What did i do wrong?

Comment: When I run this code, I get `It is definitely nice to meet you tony !`

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "+" Instead of commas since you're adding the input. like so:

```
print('It is definitely nice to meet you '+nm+'!')
```

Comment: i added a space after you so it doesnt print "youTony" but "you Tony".

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the OP's error message: `name "tony" is not defined`?

Comment: @PM2Ring you are right. I misunderstood the question. Thank you for pointing it out.