# Python List is not giving output in Quotes

Tags: python-3.x

So, I am on a coding challenge site and I am trying to solve a problem. The expected output of the problem is this:-

```
['32']
['32', 'hello', '54']
```

Now, when I solved it on my system i.e. made a `.py` file ran on terminal. It's output it same as shown above.

But on that site where I am doing this challenge, it's showing this output:-

```
[32]
[32, hello, 54]
```

I am banging my head on this. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is exactly.

I tried `str()`, quoting it with `''`, but nothing seems to work on this site's coding console.

Any idea why is it happening?

For reference here is the problem description and my code.

**Problem**

1. Your task is to maintain a list and perform two types of queries on
   it :
2. Query '1' : It will be given as 1 x  : Insert x into the list.
3. Query '2' : It will be given as 2 : Print the contents of the list.

**Code**

```
def main():

    n_of_queries = int(input("Queries count: "))
    n_list=[]
    for i in range(n_of_queries):
        inp= input("Input: ")
        typ = inp.split(' ')
        if typ[0]=='1':
            n_list.append(typ[1])
        if typ[0]=='2':
            print(n_list)

main()
```

**Input**

```
5
1 32
2
1 hello
1 54
2
```

Comment: Show the code. at least that part where you create a list

Comment: Here it is. `inp= input("Input: ")
        typ = inp.split(' ')
        if typ[0]=='1':
            n_list.append(typ[1])
        elif typ[0]=='2':
            print(n_list)`. If it doesn't make any sense here, then I can add it to the code but then I'll need to explain, what this program is about.

Comment: How does a value in typ[1] look like? What is there? Because as you showed in the description it consists of a python variable.

Comment: @DmytroHuz I've just added complete code along with problem description. Please take a look.

Comment: Same code produces different output on different platforms(your terminal, challenge-website)?

Comment: I checked the code in my terminal. It looks correct. Maybe the problem on the site?

Comment: @wuarmin but if a list contains string then list elements are printed inside these `''` quotes. So, how come these differences?

Comment: Maybe the site providers have monkey patched __str__ method of list ;)

Comment: @wuarmin yeah. I guess, something like this.

Comment: @the.salman.a check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined

Comment: @DmytroHuz thanks. I'll take a look.