# "yes" not defined? A little confused

Tags: python, function

Returns an error on restart `'yes' is not defined`. A noob to python, so not very sure what's wrong here.

```py
restart = input("Would you like to play again? ").lower
if restart == ("yes"):
    print("Restarting.. ")
    main()
elif restart == ("no"):
    print("Bye! ")
    exit()

main()
```

I want for when the user types yes or no, it either exits the program or re-runs `main()`.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I suspect you might be using Python 2, in which case you need `raw_input`, not `input`.

Comment: 1. Show us all the relevant code (this is not even a [mcve]) 2. If you are using Python 2 you should use `raw_input` instead of `input `3. you mean `.lower()`, not `.lower`, 4. You seem to use an infinite recursion here, which is bad in the long run.

Comment: Hello friend. You want to use `raw_input` instead of `input` in Python 2. `input` is actually trying the evaluate the input as Python code, which is very rarely what anybody wants. This was changed in Python 3.

Comment: @Jeremy Thank you! It works now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

```
 restart = raw_input("Would you like to play again? ").lower()
 if restart == ("yes"):
    print("Restarting.. ")
    main()
 elif restart == ("no"):
  print("Bye! ")
  exit()

 main()
```

since you are using python 2 your code should be like that