# Single line inputs for a list in Python 3

Tags: python, list

Is there some way to take a set number of multiple inputs for a list in Python 3.7?

I tried this:

```
MyList=[int(x) for x in input().split(" ",N)]
```

when N is the number inputs I want.
but whenever I try to run my code I get an error saying:

```
MyList=[int(x) for x in input().split(" ",N)]
File "<string>", line 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The expected Input is:-

Suppose N=7,

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

This should make it a part of the list

MyList=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Comment: You haven't actually shown an error. But what is that `N` at the end?

Comment: `[int(x) for x in input().split()]`

Comment: @Mr_U4913 split splits on space by default can just use .split()

Comment: @Daniel Roseman N stands for the number of elements, in this case its the max split

Comment: Fine but *what is the error*? And where did you define the value of N?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman The error is that it won't accept the single line inputs. It say's invalid syntax. As for N, the user defines it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `N` argument to `split`. If there are more items in the input than this, the remaining ones will all be combined in the last element of the list. But this won't be a valid number, so you'll get an error when it tries to convert that to `int`.

If you only want the first `N` elements of the input, use a list slice after splitting.

```
MyList=[int(x) for x in input().split(" ")[:N]]
```

It looks like you're using Python 2.x, so you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. See [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined).

```
MyList=[int(x) for x in raw_input().split(" ")[:N]]
```

Comment: Are you typing the input, or did you put the input in the script?

Comment: I am typing the input

Comment: Then the error you reported can't happen. It's marking that as a syntax error in the script.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: If you're using 2.x you need to use `raw_input()`.

Comment: I am using python 3.7

Comment: I thnk you're mistaken. I tried your code in Python 2, I got your error. Python 3 doesn't try to parse the input.