# I have an error in my script trying to calculate the retirement age

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to calculate the age of a person, to verify whether or not he is of retirement age. This is python 2.7

```
from datetime import datetime

def getName():
  name = input("What is your name?: ")
  return name

def getAge():
  age = input("How old are you?: ")
  return int(age)

def ifOrNot():
  retirementAge = 65
  if(getAge() >= retirementAge):
    print("Hello  ",getName(), ", are you in retirment age")
  else:
    timeToRetirement = retirementAge - getAge()
    print("Hello ", getName(), " are you not in retirement age, you need to wait ", timeToRetirement, " more").

def main():
  ifOrNot()

main()
```

The question "how old are you" appears on the screen twice. Then the question "What's your name" is displayed once. And then these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 22, in
<module>
    main()   File "main.py", line 20, in main
    ifOrNot()   File "main.py", line 17, in ifOrNot
    print("Hola ", getName(), " aun no estas en edad de retiro, te faltan ", timeToRetirement)   File "main.py", line 4, in getName
    name = input("What is your name?: ")   File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'Diesan' is not defined
```

I want to ask for the name first, then the age, and calculate the remaining years to be able to retirement.
Curiosly, I do not need to use `datetime`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def getName():
  name = input("What is your name?: ")
  return name
```

[`input()` in python2.7 tries to evaluate whatever it gets as a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122817/7431860) - use `raw_input()` instead to get the string, which will be returned as a plain string.

```
def ifOrNot():
  retirementAge = 65
  if(getAge() >= retirementAge):
    print("Hello  ",getName(), ", are you in retirment age")
  else:
    timeToRetirement = retirementAge - getAge()
    print("Hello ", getName(), " are you not in retirement age, you need to wait ", timeToRetirement, " more").
```

If you're not of retirement age, `getAge()` will be called once in the first `if` statement, and then again inside the `else` statement. Consider assigning the result got `getAge()` to a variable and reusing it. Also, you've got a stray `.` at the end of your second `print()` statement.

You are correct, you do not need to use `datetime`.

Correct code is as follows:

```
def getName():
  name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
  return name

def getAge():
  age = input("How old are you?: ")
  return int(age)

def ifOrNot():
  retirementAge = 65
  myAge = getAge()
  if(myAge >= retirementAge):
    print("Hello  ",getName(), ", are you in retirment age")
  else:
    timeToRetirement = retirementAge - myAge
    print("Hello ", getName(), " are you not in retirement age, you need to wait ", timeToRetirement, " more")

def main():
  ifOrNot()

main()
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/FinishedScholarlyTab)

Answer (score 1):

Keep the answers in variables:

```
def ifOrNot():
    retirementAge = 65
    name = getName()
    age = getAge()
    if (age >= retirementAge):
        print("Hello  ", name, ", are you in retirment age")
    else:
        timeToRetirement = retirementAge - age
        print("Hello ", getName(), " are you not in retirement age, you need to wait ", timeToRetirement, " more").
```