# Python string input gives error unless with quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I thought the `input` method will take any numeric or string input and print it out. But for `string` it does not work unless `string` is in quoted. Why?

[image: string input]

Comment: Please post the code as text not images

Comment: in what environment are you trying this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.7, `input()` evaluates the input as code, so strings need to be quoted. Python 2.7 has a method called `raw_input()` that treats all input as strings (no quotes needed).

In Python 3.x, the Python 2.7 `raw_input()` method was renamed `input()` and the Python 2.7 `input()` functionality was replaced by `eval(input())`

So you can use `raw_input()` in Python 2.7 or switch to Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running the code on Python 3 and not Python 2.
On python 2 you are needed to quote your input with ""

it seems like there are multiple solution to this though:

[input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)