# Why am I getting a NameError when I use input() in Python 2?

Tags: python, variables, input

I am getting a classic

NameError : name 'Y' is not defined.

I know this is extreme beginner level and a multitude of similar questions have been answered. 
However none of the answers have helped me fix this simple issue. Replies would be greatly appreciated.

def intro ():

```
#checks if the user already has an account and redirects accordingly

print("ARE YOU A REGISTERED USER? [Y/N]")
redirect = input()
if redirect == "Y" :
    print("OK")
else :
    print("gtfo")
```

intro()

Comment: Why are you using Python 2? It has reached its end of life and is no longer supported. You need to change to Python 3 and this problem wouldn't exist (in python 2, you need `raw_input` for this)

Comment: Oh geez i havent checked the version, just started with the one that came with linux when I switched from windows. Thank you very much

Comment: It may be as simple as changing `python my_script.py` to `python3 my_script.py` if there is already a Python 3 installation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Python 2. Try using [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input()`. [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) on Python 2 is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(string))`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me using python3, you can add a way to also check lower case inputs.

```
def intro():
    redirect = input("ARE YOU A REGISTERED USER? [Y/N] ")
    if redirect == "Y" :
        print("OK")
    else :
        print("gtfo")


intro()
exit = input("press any key to exit")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined