# Error: NameError: name 'Caitlin' is not defined

Tags: python

Could you please tell me why I am getting this error? When I enter the input I am expecting a string but I get the below error instead,

```
File "ifelif.py", line 1, in <module> first_name = input("What is your first name? ") File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'Caitlin' is not defined
```

I am using this code:

```
first_name = input("What is your first name? ") 
print("Hello,", first_name) 
if first_name == "Caitlin": 
 print(first_name, "is learning Python") 
 print("Have a great day {}!".format(first_name))
```

When I enter the name in the Terminal with quotes to make a string, it works but I get 2 strings instead of 1 string :

```
('Hello,', 'Ed')
```

The name of the file is 'ifelif.py'

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined/21122817

Comment: Does this answer your question? [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: @adamgy Thanks! This really helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python2 you should be using `raw_input`. In Python2 `input` will evaluate what you type which is why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

tested your code. looks fine with me. no error at all. it behave the way I expect it to do, or what is your output expectation?

```
first_name = input("What is your first name? ") 
print("Hello,", first_name) 
if first_name == "Caitlin": 
 print(first_name, "is learning Python") 
 print("Have a great day {}!".format(first_name))
```

1st input: boy, output is:

```
What is your first name? boy
Hello, boy
```

2nd input: Caitlin, output is:

```
What is your first name? Caitlin
Hello, Caitlin
Caitlin is learning Python
Have a great day Caitlin!
```

this is probably just code writing style/preference, but I would do it like:

```
print(f"{first_name} is learning Python") 
print(f"Have a great day {first_name}!")
```

it's called "f string print" where you put the variable in curly bracket