# NameError: name '<name>' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I'm trying to create a script that plays the Name Game in text.  Got stuck using my first class.

```
def AskName():
    print("\n\nLet's play the Name Game!\n  Based on the song written by Shirly Ellis and Lincoln Case.\n")
    GivenName = input("What is your first name? --> ")
    print("\n")
    global GivenName
```

Call it later on (it's the first class called) and I keep getting this...
(Say I entered "David".)

> ```
> ./namegame.py:27: SyntaxWarning: name 'GivenName' is assigned to
> before global declaration   global GivenName
>
>
> Let's play the Name Game!   Based on the song written by Shirly Ellis
> and Lincoln Case.
>
> What is your first name? --> David
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "./namegame.py", line 78, in <module>
>     AskName()   File "./namegame.py", line 25, in AskName
>     GivenName = input("What is your first name? --> ")
> File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'David' is not defined
> ```

I had GivenName as not global, and I added the following as suggested on similar issues:

```
if __name__== "__main__":
  AskName()
```

The error persists.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You think you're on Python 3, but you're not. Get Python 3.

Comment: In python 2, python will attempt to compile an execute what is typed in for `input`. Python 2 uses `raw_input` for strings. Python 3 ditched the `input` functionality and renamed `raw_input` to `input`. It really looks like you are running python 2.

Comment: The other error is exactly what it says. You have to put `global GivenName` above any use of `GivenName` in the function.

Comment: You shouldn't use global variables (there are exceptions to this “rule”). Return the GivenName from the function instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

I had tried not having GivenName as a global variable, but I tried it again.  Same NameError.

Using input versus raw_input didn't make a difference.  Same NameError.

I'll see if my version of Python is up to date.  That may be it.

Comment: I updated Python; it's now version 3.8.3.  Sadly, no dice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making is in global declaration of `GivenName`, if you are using any variable as global the line `global GivenName` should be always first in any function although it is not mandatory.Your code should look like this,

```
#if the variable is global it should be defined in global scope first and then you can use it
GivenName=""
def AskName():

    global GivenName
    print("\n\nLet's play the Name Game!\n  Based on the song written by Shirly Ellis and Lincoln Case.\n")
    GivenName = input("What is your first name? --> ")
    print("\n")

if __name__== "__main__":
  AskName()
```

hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but when I tried this, the same NameError occurred.