# I get Traceback (most recent call last) each time I run this code, how to fix this?

Tags: python, debugging

I run this code on PyCharm 2.7 and each time I enter an input as a name I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Korisnik/PycharmProjects/untitled/Program test.py", line 4, in <module>
    character_name = input("Select a name for your character: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'aaa' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there any way to fix this? I am a beginner in python scripting so an explanation on how to fix this would be great.

This is my code:

```
print("-- Story generator by Mateo Primorac --")

character_name = input("Select a name for your character: ")
character_age = input("Select the age for your character: ")
character_gender = input("Select a gender for your character: ")
character_color = input("Select your characters favorite color: ")

if character_gender == "male" or "Male":
    print("There was once a man called " + character_name + ",")
    print("He is " + character_age + " years old.")
    print("He likes wearing " + character_color + " shirts and pants because that is his favorite color.")
    print("Press space or enter to exit.")
    input()
    quit()

if character_gender == "female" or "Female":
    print("There was once a woman called " + character_name + ",")
    print("She is " + character_age + " years old.")
    print("She likes wearing " + character_color + " shirts and dresses because that is her favorite color.")
    print("Press space or enter to exit.")
    input()
    quit()
```

Comment: You're writing your code like it's Python 3, but running it on Python 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: My question is answered by LeopardShark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is Python 2, you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. (Or switch to Python 3)

Comment: Thank you! This works. I will accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "OR" to "AND" and run in python 3

You can use this website for python 3

repl.it

Here is your code: https://repl.it/repls/DarkvioletRealLocatorprogram#main.py

Answer (score 0):

Use **raw_input** in place of **input** in **python2**. 
Ex:- character_name = **raw_input("Select a name for your character: ")**