# im pretty much a noob to coding in pycharm,

Tags: python, input, pycharm

this question should be really simple, but since im a noob to python I have no idea what to do here.

the code that I sent was:

```
print("what is your name?")
name=input()
```

then this error would appear when I tried to run it:

```
name '(namethatwasinput)' is not defined
```

it worked before so i have no idea what's going on, can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

try using

name = input("what's your name: ")

Comment: Pawel has given you the very best answer to your question!  However I have tried your code using Thonny and Python 3.11 and your code works fine if you use print(name) to display what you have input.  What code did you use to output the variable to your screen?