# Simple Python Telnetlib Script in GNS3

Tags: python

> Hello,
>
> I am just playing around in GNS3 and having issues with telnetting in
> from an Ubuntu docker using a Python script, to a router. I have
> confirmed connectivity and they are both setup with NAT to hit
> external sites successfully. I can also telnet from the router to the
> same router (for testing purposes), so I know it's working. Here is my
> script, which is basically a slightly edited version from the example:
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html
>
> import getpass import telnetlib
>
> HOST = "10.168.122.223" user = input("Enter your telnet password: ")
> password = getpass.getpass()
>
> tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
>
> tn.read_until(b"Username: ") tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n") if
> password:
> tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
> tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
>
> tn.write(b"ls\n") tn.write(b"exit\n")
>
> print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
>
> When I execute the above, the following error comes back:
>
> root@UbuntuDockerGuest-2:~# python PythonR1Script1 Enter your telnet
> username:  joe Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "PythonR1Script1", line 6, in    user = input("Enter your telnet username: ")
> File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'joe' is not defined
>
> I am following David Bombal's Python for Networking Engineers here,
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhroIrV9_7w&ab_channel=DavidBombal,
> and he is using virtually the same commands although he is using
> Python2 and I'm using Python3. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Wow, I am a noob. I formatted the above so bad, and I apologize for that. I may need a lesson on how to propose coding questions lol.

Comment: You can still fix it by using the [edit] button.

Comment: However, the solution seems simply to use `python3` instead of `python` to start the script.

Comment: This should answer your question: [input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122540/input-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thank you guys. I feel a bit dumb on that one. I don't believe you have to specify that on Windows? But was using Ubuntu here so specified python3 (filename), and it worked like a charm. Thanks again!